# Ubuntu 18.04 not recognizing ram correctly

Tags: 18.04, ram

As I am new here, please be indulgent if my question is not posed with the highest possible precision. Also, I am far from being an expert, so if you don't mind rather explain a bit more than less ;)

So here is the question: recently I upgraded my desktop from 4gb to now 8gb (4*2gb pc2 6400, identical sticks). But apparently, only 4gb are used as can be seen e.g. in the system monitoring tool. How can I make the full ram available to ubuntu?

Here are some of the things I already tried based on a google research (apologies for the German terms in there, but I think it is understandable anyways):

**`sudo lshw | grep product | head -n1 && sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-manufacturer`**

```
11/04/2009 
P5B-DE 
ASRock
```

**`lsb_release -a`**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 
LTS Release:    18.04 
Codename:   bionic
```

**`uname -m`**

```
x86_64
```

**`sudo lshw -C memory`**

```
*-firmware                
       Beschreibung: BIOS
       Hersteller: American Megatrends Inc.
       Physische ID: 0
       Version: P1.10
       date: 11/04/2009
       Größe: 64KiB
       Kapazität: 448KiB
       Fähigkeiten: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification netboot
  *-cache:0
       Beschreibung: L1 Cache
       Physische ID: 5
       Steckplatz: L1-Cache
       Größe: 128KiB
       Kapazität: 128KiB
       Fähigkeiten: internal write-back data
       Konfiguration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       Beschreibung: L2 Cache
       Physische ID: 6
       Steckplatz: L2-Cache
       Größe: 6MiB
       Kapazität: 6MiB
       Fähigkeiten: internal write-back unified
       Konfiguration: level=2
  *-memory
       Beschreibung: Systemspeicher
       Physische ID: 13
       Steckplatz: Systemplatine oder Hauptplatine
       Größe: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          Beschreibung: DIMM SDRAM Synchron
          Produkt: ModulePartNumber00
          Hersteller: Manufacturer00
          Physische ID: 0
          Seriennummer: SerNum00
          Steckplatz: DIMM0
          Größe: 2GiB
          Breite: 64 bits
     *-bank:1
          Beschreibung: DIMM SDRAM Synchron
          Produkt: ModulePartNumber01
          Hersteller: Manufacturer01
          Physische ID: 1
          Seriennummer: SerNum01
          Steckplatz: DIMM1
          Größe: 2GiB
          Breite: 64 bits
     *-bank:2
          Beschreibung: DIMM SDRAM Synchron
          Produkt: ModulePartNumber02
          Hersteller: Manufacturer02
          Physische ID: 2
          Seriennummer: SerNum02
          Steckplatz: DIMM2
          Größe: 2GiB
          Breite: 64 bits
     *-bank:3
          Beschreibung: DIMM SDRAM Synchron
          Produkt: ModulePartNumber03
          Hersteller: Manufacturer03
          Physische ID: 3
          Seriennummer: SerNum03
          Steckplatz: DIMM3
          Größe: 2GiB
          Breite: 64 bits
```

**`free -m`**

```
              Gesamt   belegt    frei        gemns. Puffer/Cache verfügbar
Speicher:        3440        2072         188         256        1179         946
Auslagerungsspeicher:         975           1         974
```

**`cat /proc/meminfo`**

```
MemTotal:        3523408 kB
MemFree:          230724 kB
MemAvailable:    1007608 kB
Buffers:           85464 kB
Cached:          1051948 kB
SwapCached:          208 kB
Active:          2183460 kB
Inactive:         826504 kB
Active(anon):    1742536 kB
Inactive(anon):   385396 kB
Active(file):     440924 kB
Inactive(file):   441108 kB
Unevictable:          48 kB
Mlocked:              48 kB
SwapTotal:        999420 kB
SwapFree:         998128 kB
Dirty:               940 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1872508 kB
Mapped:           654040 kB
Shmem:            255384 kB
Slab:             120496 kB
SReclaimable:      63912 kB
SUnreclaim:        56584 kB
KernelStack:       12624 kB
PageTables:        44400 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     2761124 kB
Committed_AS:    5910900 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      267904 kB
DirectMap2M:     3336192 kB
```

If additional info is needed just ask :)

**UPDATE**

As suggested in the comments I started to exchange the sticks among the slots. There are 4 slots (call them 0,1,2, and 3; 0 and 2 yellow, 1 and 3 red) and 4 sticks (call them A,B,C, and D). The order of the slots remains the same all the time and I switched the sticks into the following orders:

- ABCD (this was the state when I posed the question)
- ACBD
- ADBC
- ADCB
- BDCA
- BCDA

For each configuration I ran the same commands as above and compared the outputs. With regard to the relevant parameters they were exactly equal (e.g. MemTotal:        3523408 kB), which leads me to the conclusion that my problem is not caused by the order of the sticks. Thus, the question remains how to enable the full ram?!

**UPDATE II**

I tested every stick by putting it into slot 0 with all other sticks removed. They all work properly and the output of the commands shown above are identical with respect to the relevant parameters.

Also, I checked that my CPU (Intel Q9400) supports 64bit instructions. Thus, both mainboard and CPU should be OK with 4 identical sticks of 2gb each. I deduce from the uname -m command that I am using the 64bit version of ubuntu. Therefore, I assume that there are no more hardware issues to be checked, it seems to be a configuration issue.

**UPDATE III**

In another post I learned that BIOS reserves some of the memory and that in some cases this can be a significat amount. Therefore I tried

**dmesg | grep -i memory**

```
[    0.000000] Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009f000-0x0009ffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000e3fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000e4000-0x000fffff]
[    0.000000] Memory: 3476560K/3603704K available (12300K kernel code, 2481K rwdata, 4264K rodata, 2432K init, 2712K bss, 127144K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.033802] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 36K
[    0.172309] x86/mm: Memory block size: 128MB
[    0.856931] Freeing initrd memory: 40492K
[    0.857215] Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
[    1.930475] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 2432K
[    1.949109] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 2008K
[    1.949955] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 1880K
```

where the 7th line tells me that this is not the case for me.

Comment: Have you tried to insert them one pair of sticks separately to check if them all are recognized by Ubuntu. Also by inserting the same pair in different slots with the other two slots empty in different positions? Are all 4 sticks detected by BIOS?

Comment: So far I did not exchange any of the sticks in any fashion. To check that they are recognized somehow I did the following:
* windows recongnizes 8gb, but reserves much more for the system than ubuntu
* as in the output of the lshw command, the memory check (when booting) sees that there are 4*2gb, I do not know how to copy this screen
* next I will look whether BIOS detects the sticks, I will then post the answer here

Comment: BIOS does recognize a total of 8192MB divided among the 4*2gb (DDR2 667)

Comment: Try also sticks replacement.

Comment: some motherboards require different configurations of RAM to be installed in particular slots.  example: if your board has 4 slots and you have 2 sticks of RAM, they may need to be in slots 1&3.  Check the documentation on your motherboard.  Also, are you certain that you have installed the 64-bit version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Does it show 4gbs of ram is you just put in the new sticks and not the old ones?

Comment: I checked the MB manual: "This motherboard also allows you to install fourDDR2 DIMMs for dual channel configuration, and please install identical DDR2DIMMs in all four slots.", therefore I believe what I am trying to do must be possible.
I exchanged the sticks, see update of original question for results
@Robby1212: the old sticks are removed, I inserted 4 completely new, identical ones

Comment: two other things to check: have you tried to use only one stick at a time? (to verify that each stick works by itself)  -- also, are you using **DDR2**?  DDR2 is from the era of 32-bit computing.  If your CPU cannot handle 64-bit instructions and/or if your OS is installed as 32-bit, the max amount of RAM that can be used is around 4GB.  This is the most RAM that can be utilized with 32-bit software.

Comment: I addressed your suggestions in the above update of the initial post, the problem remains

Comment: I am still stuck and I would really appreciate if there was somebody with more ideas of what to try

Comment: @nmath Standard 18.04 is 64-bit only, so the OP should state the particular flavor used. In 32-bit mode you still can use >4GB RAM with the PAE kernels. But that could be a BIOS issue.

Comment: @xenoid I thought that 'uname -m' tells me the flavor I am using, where 'x86_64' tells me 64bit and 'i386' tells me 32bit. If there is another way of finding out or my assumption is wrong I would be happy to learn.

Comment: I was answering @Nmath hypothesis tat you are running 32-bi-t. If `uname -m` says `x86-64` then you are running 64-bit.